# Add dropdown and checkbox values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the values from the  and a checkbox, and put the value in a text box OR add the dropdown and checkbox if both are selected and put that into a text box.  There is a JavaScript error in the code, which you can see in the link below, in IE but it works correctly in Chrome.  Any guidance on this?

```
function TotAmt() {
   var DA = +document.getElementById("Donation").options[Donation.selectedIndex].value;
   if (document.form1.somename.checked == true) {
      document.form1.Summary.value = parseInt(DA) + parseInt(500);
   } else {
      document.form1.Summary.value = parseInt(DA);
   }
}
```

[View sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/FLrW8/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get rid of that specific error in jsFiddle by not wrapping the javascript in the head. Then use `getElementById` function in your `ToAtm()` function like this:

```
function fnchecked(blnchecked) {
    if (blnchecked) {
        document.getElementById("CoatSizeDiv").style.display = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("CoatSizeDiv").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function TotAmt() {
    var DA = +document.getElementById("Donation").options[Donation.selectedIndex].value;
    if (document.getElementById("somename").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("Summary").value = parseInt(DA) + parseInt(500);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Summary").value = parseInt(DA);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[UPDATED CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/FLrW8/2/)</kbd>

Comment: You're right, I should have used the getElementByID.  So you're saying these JS functions should not be in the head, but in the body?

Comment: No, for them to work in jaFiddle you need to remove the wrapper. I would personally put these in the head.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I can get the code working in Chrome and FireFox on my website but IE isn't doing anything and is not show any errors.  Good old IE. LOL

Comment: No errors, hmmm Is the function being called at all? Maybe print something on the console or try and do something  else./

Comment: I keep having it show this error "SCRIPT5009: 'Donation' is undefined 
" and it points to the line that starts with "var DA = ...."

Comment: It's probably complaining about you using the id of the element, and that + sign. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FLrW8/3/ it uses getElementById once again

Comment: That's what it was.  Thanks!